# How to render a doctype with Python's xml.dom.minidom?

Tags: python, xml, doctype

I tried:

```
document.doctype = xml.dom.minidom.DocumentType('html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"')
```

There is no doctype in the output. How to fix without inserting it by hand?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You shouldn't instantiate classes from `minidom` directly. It's not a supported part of the API, the `ownerDocument`​s won't tie up and you can get some strange misbehaviours. Instead use the proper DOM Level 2 Core methods:

```
>>> imp= minidom.getDOMImplementation('')
>>> dt= imp.createDocumentType('html', '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN', 'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd')
```

(‘DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd’ is a commonly-used but wrong `SystemId`. That relative URL would only be valid inside the xhtml1 folder at w3.org.)

Now you've got a `DocumentType` node, you can add it to a document. According to the standard, the only guaranteed way of doing this is at document creation time:

```
>>> doc= imp.createDocument('http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml', 'html', dt)
>>> print doc.toxml()
<?xml version="1.0" ?><!DOCTYPE html  PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN'  'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd'><html/>
```

If you want to change the doctype of an existing document, that's more trouble. The DOM standard doesn't require that `DocumentType` nodes with no `ownerDocument` be insertable into a document. However some DOMs allow it, eg. `pxdom`. `minidom` kind of allows it:

```
>>> doc= minidom.parseString('<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head/><body/></html>')
>>> dt= minidom.getDOMImplementation('').createDocumentType('html', '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN', 'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd')
>>> doc.insertBefore(dt, doc.documentElement)
<xml.dom.minidom.DocumentType instance>
>>> print doc.toxml()
<?xml version="1.0" ?><!DOCTYPE html  PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN'  'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd'><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head/><body/></html>
```

but with bugs:

```
>>> doc.doctype
# None
>>> dt.ownerDocument
# None
```

which may or may not matter to you.

Technically, the only reliable way per the standard to set a doctype on an existing document is to create a new document and import the whole of the old document into it!

```
def setDoctype(document, doctype):
    imp= document.implementation
    newdocument= imp.createDocument(doctype.namespaceURI, doctype.name, doctype)
    newdocument.xmlVersion= document.xmlVersion
    refel= newdocument.documentElement
    for child in document.childNodes:
        if child.nodeType==child.ELEMENT_NODE:
            newdocument.replaceChild(
                newdocument.importNode(child, True), newdocument.documentElement
            )
            refel= None
        elif child.nodeType!=child.DOCUMENT_TYPE_NODE:
            newdocument.insertBefore(newdocument.importNode(child, True), refel)
    return newdocument
```

Comment: thanks! I don't need to set doctype on existing document, just on new.